# How to find line of code causing wordpress deprecation notices

Tags: debug

My Site gives a few errors about notices and depreciations that I would like to fix.  For example:

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  add_option was called with an argument that is **deprecated** since version 2.3.0 with no alternative available. in /home/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5067

The line of code it referes to is not the cause of the error, it is the Wordpress debug code intercepting the error. How do I find out the actual line causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the error message refers to a line in a WordPress core file instead of a theme or plugin is because it's within the function itself that the error occurs, not in the place where `add_option()` is called.

If you want to be able to trace through the code to discover the originating file, you can use an extension like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), which will allow you to generate a stack trace, like this one:

[image: example xdebug stack trace]

From this we can see that the offending plugin is called `example.php`, and the function that calls `add_option` incorrectly is called `some_buggy_function()`.

As far as fixing the error itself, previous versions of WordPress used a third argument to `add_option` which is now deprecated. Removing that argument or setting it to an empty string `''` will remove the warning.

Comment: It's probably not great to add xdebug to production server.  I could download the site and run it locally to debug.  Hopefully wordpress will fix it at some point.

Comment: @Will it doesn't need to be permanent, you could install and just switch on long enough to receive the stack trace, and then turn off. Agreed that error debugging should happen in a local server. This isn't something WordPress can fix; it's likely an issue with your theme or plugins

Comment: This kind of stuff comes up loads with WP, because there is all sorts of code thanks to plugins & themes.   "install xdebug on production" can't be the right answer.

Comment: What else is WordPress core supposed to do? The correct answer is to not use plugins or themes containing outdated code, especially on production.

Comment: Theme and plugin issues are inevitable - wordpress should show the error with enough detail to debug it.

Comment: @will it absolutely does! once you turn on debug mode like I suggested. Don't be surprised that you can't debug an error message if you're trying to run things in production mode

Comment: it doesnt.  read the question

Comment: @Will the "WordPress debug code" is not intercepting the error; it is generating it without the means to tell where exactly the function was originally called.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run a RegEx search in your editor for `add_option\(.+,.+,.+\);` and check the results manually. Shouldn't be too much. Alternatively you can run  or running `$ grep -r 'add_option\(.+,.+,.+\);' .` from your command line

Comment: I dont think that will work.  What we really need to know is what the argument was that was invalid.  In a dynamic theme like a pagerbuilder for example, that could be calling add_option many times, with many different arguments.  It's normal for a system to give the actual error.  Wordpress is intercepting the error and giving less detail than if it didn't.